# Quicksort with duplicate values in object arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, object, quicksort

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Staff[] staffs = new Staff[10];
        Staff[] answer = new Staff[staffs.length];
        int temp = 0;
        
        
        staffs[0] = new Staff(1,"J","IT");
        staffs[1] = new Staff(3,"I","IT");
        staffs[2] = new Staff(2,"H","GA");
        staffs[3] = new Staff(7,"G","GA");
        staffs[4] = new Staff(5,"F","AUDIT");
        staffs[5] = new Staff(6,"E","AUDIT");
        staffs[6] = new Staff(4,"D","IT");
        staffs[7] = new Staff(10,"C","IT");
        staffs[8] = new Staff(9,"B","HR");
        staffs[9] = new Staff(8,"A","HR");
        
        
        PrintArray(staffs);
        quickSort(staffs, 0, staffs.length-1);
        PrintArray(staffs);
    }
    private static void quickSort(Staff[] staffs, int start, int end)
    {

            int i = start;
            int j = end;
            if (j - i >= 1)
            {
                String pivot = staffs[i].dep;
                while (j > i)
                {

                    while (staffs[i].dep.compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && i < end && j > i){
                        i++;
                    }

                    while (staffs[j].dep.compareTo(pivot) >= 0 && j > start && j >= i){
                        j--;
                    }
                    
                    if (j > i)
                        swap(staffs, i, j);
                }

            
                swap(staffs, start, j);
                quickSort(staffs, start, j - 1);
                quickSort(staffs, j + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static void swap(Staff[] staffs, int i, int j)
        {
        Staff temp = staffs[i];
        staffs[i] = staffs[j];
        staffs[j] = temp;
        }
    public static void PrintArray(Staff[] staffs) {
        for(int a = 0; a<staffs.length; a++) {
            System.out.println(staffs[a].id+", "+staffs[a].name+", "+staffs[a].dep);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

I sorted this object array in quicksort algorithm.
It will be sorted by department value.
But the thing is there are duplicated department value.
I want to code that if there is duplicate value in department column,
then sorting object by ascending order of id.

How can i handle this?

Comment: You write that this code sorts by department, but it actually sorts by name. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry, i modified it.

Comment: Please do not remove the information that was essential to your question. I rolled back the destructive edit you made.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `compareTo` method on your `Staff` class, which performs a comparison based on `dep` and `id` (when there is a tie):

```
    int compareTo(Staff other) {
        int res = dep.compareTo(other.dep);
        return res != 0 ? res : id - other.id;
    }
```

Now in your `quickSort` code, just compare using this method:

```
            Staff pivot = staffs[i];
            while (j > i)
            {
                while (staffs[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && i < end && j > i) {
                    i++;
                }
                while (staffs[j].compareTo(pivot) >= 0 && j > start && j >= i) {
                    j--;
                }
                if (j > i)
                    swap(staffs, i, j);
            }
```